# Magento 2 - Enable the authorisation login popup modal

Tags: magento-2.1, login, popup, modal, authorize

How do I activate the authorize Login popup modal for Magento 2?

Like shown below. Is this a Extension or can I activate this by configuration or by edits in my Theme?

[image]